# Else If on input Flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, if-statement, flash-cs6

I'm a complete noobie with Flash and AS3. I have this simple idea but I'm almost positive I need some guidance by the pros. I think I figured I need an if-else statement in my AS3.

Simple little animation. I have the lost TV show counter and computer displayed. I want them to enter a certain set of numbers into the computer and press enter. IF they enter the correct numbers I want it to play a congratulations message. If they don't I just want the screen to shake. How could I make sure the numbers they enter are correct.

I'm thinking back to my java days but it has been so long!

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Make an input textfield called textBox, and have a frame label called "shake" for shaking the screen (which comes back to the input) and a frame label called "success" for when the code is entered correctly.

Put this on the frame with the textfield

```
if (textBox.text == "PASSWORD") {
    gotoAndPlay("shake");
} else {
    gotoAndPlay("success");
}
```

Comment: Works perfect for now! No I have to create my shake and success layers. I appreciate the help!

Comment: If you want this to run on a button press just add a movieclip called "submitBtn" and use this code instead:

import flash.events.MouseEvent;

submitBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, testPassword);

function testPassword(e:MouseEvent):void {
    if (textBox.text == "PASSWORD") {
        gotoAndPlay("shake");
    } else {
        gotoAndPlay("success");
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

```
if (numberEntered == correctNumber) {
  //doCongratsMessage
} else {
  //boomboomboomShaketheroom
}
```

Comment: I want the user to enter these numbers " 4 8 15 16 23 42" Will this work with multiple numbers?

Comment: depends if you want them to be entered in that order or not

Comment: Perfect, I got it to work so it enters the numbers, however I cant get it to actually submit the input text to take it to the next frame.